# Having trouble remotely debugging nodejs from headless server

Tags: node.js, node-inspector, node-debugger

I'm running node from a headless ubuntu server and I'm having trouble reaching node-inspector from an external browser.

I can do it on another server of mine that had an older version of node or node-inspector, by navigating to this link and swapping localhost for the server ip:

```
debugger listening on port 5858
Node Inspector is now available from http://localhost:8080/debug?port=5858
```

I just provisioned a new server and installed node on it, but node-debug now shows this format:

```
debugger listening on port 5858
Node Inspector is now available from http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?ws=127.0.0.1:8080&port=5858
```

I can't seem to hit that by swapping the ip address anymore.. Is there an extra step required in forwarding anything?